# A react `useReducer` with some dependencies

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

i'm creating a react component: `TxtEditor`
Inside the editor, there is a `useReducer` hook for manipulating the text:
APPEND => to alter the current text.
UPPERCASE => to convert uppercase letter.

But the reducer function is not **a pure function**. There are some dependencies:
`props.disabled` => ignores all the reducer actions.
`props.onTxtChanged` => will be executed after the text has modified.

So I created the reducer function *inside* the function component.
This is a problem for `useReducer` because each time the component rendered, a new identical function with different by reference always re-created.
Thus making `useReducer` executing the reducer function **twice** on next render -and- triggering `props.onTxtChanged` twice too. I don't know why react doing this.

Then to solve the problem, I wrapped the reducer function with `useCallback`.
It seem be working, but NOT. Because the `props.onTxtChanged` **might** be passed by user with `an inline function`. And the function always be re-created (identical but different by reference), thus making `useCallback` useless.

And finally I created a reducer function **outside** the function component.
The function is always the same by reference and making `useReducer` working properly.
To inject the dependencies I made a **HACK** like this:

```
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(txtReducer, /*initialState: */{
    text  : 'hello',
    props : props, // HACK: a dependency is injected here
  });
  state.props = props; // HACK: a dependency is updated here
```

So the `props` can be accessed in the reducer function:

```
const txtReducer = (state, action) => {
  const props = state.props;
  if (props.disabled) return state; // disabled => no change
}
```

It's working but it contain a hack.
I want **the professional way** doing this stuff.
Do you have any suggestion?

[See the complete sandbox code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-reducer-with-dependencies-t6twt?file=/src/TxtEditor.js:51-180)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
function TxtEditor(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(txtReducer, { text  : 'hello'});

  // Wait for the state to change and only then emmit a text change
  useEffect(() => {
    props.onTextChange(state.text);
  }, [state])

  return <input onInput={handleInput} />

  function handleInput() {
    if (props.disabled) return; // <-- just don't fire an update

    // [...] call to your reducer
  }
}
```

Reducers are just a `useState` with a bit of logic. So only let them handle a (singular) state and don't make it responsible for many things at once. Also they should only be responsible for the actual state logic, not something outside, like if the text box is disabled or not.

---

A potential solution to the desired hook described in the comments of this post:

I hope you don't mind the typescript. I just find it easier to work with.

```
enum TextProcessorMode {
  APPEND,
}

interface TextProcessorActionOptions {
  disabled?: boolean;
  mode: TextProcessorMode;
}

interface TextProcesserAction {
  newText: string;
  options: TextProcessorActionOptions;
  /**
   * Is called when the text was successfully processed.
   */
  onChange(text: string): void;
}


export default function textProcessorReducer(
  state: string,
  action: TextProcesserAction
): string {
  if (action.options.disabled) return state;

  let newState: string;

  switch (action.options.mode) {
    case TextProcessorMode.APPEND:
      newState = state + action.newText;
      break;
    // Handle other modes
  }

  action.onChange(newState);
  
  return newState;
}
```

Comment: actually i want to create a custom hook. I want the conditional logic & event to be processed inside the hook. Something like this: `const [text, dispatch] = useTextProcessor('hello', props)`, the hook will be shared to multiple component, so each component has a minimal code.

Comment: @HeyyyMarco hmm... that would technically be a new question. But I'll look into it. You should add it to the question/rewrite the question if that is what you wanted.

Comment: @HeyyyMarco I appended something to the answer, but for me to give you an exact one, you really had to create a new question or update the current one with more information.

Comment: ok, i'll create a new question with more detailed requirement

Comment: here my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049514/how-to-create-a-custom-usereducer-with-built-in-decision-and-event-triggering