# How to create a custom useReducer with built in decision and event triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to create a custom hook, let's say `useTextProcessor(initialText, props)`.
It's a react state for storing & manipulating text (string).
It uses `useReducer` for making cumulative state.
The code is like this:

```
interface TextEditorProps {
  disabled?: boolean
  onTextChanged?: (text: string) => void
}

const useTextProcessor = (initialText: string, props: TextEditorProps) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(textReducerFunc, /*initialState: */{
    text  : initialText,
    props : props, // HACK: a dependency is injected here
  });
  state.props = props; // HACK: a dependency is updated here

  return [
    state.text,
    dispatch
  ] as const;
}
```

There is **a hack way** to inject `props` to be accessed in `textReducerFunc`.
The `textReducerFunc` is the main function where the text is processed (depended on the action type & props state).

I've no idea how to insert the dependency `props` into `textReducerFunc` **in professional react way**.
If I declared the `textReducerFunc` inside the `useTextProcessor(initialText, props)`,
yes I can access the `props`, but wait since it's a child function, the child **always be re-created** every `useTextProcessor` called.
This makes `useReducer` executing the `textReducerFunc` **twice on the next render**.
Ut's making `onTextChanged` will be **executed twice too**.
Wrapping with `useCallback` will not have any effect since `onTextChanged` accepts any function (might be a static or inline function). The inline function is always different by reference on every render.

Here the detail of `textReducerFunc` works:

```
interface TextState {
  props: TextEditorProps // holds my hack
  text: string // the actual data to be processed
}
interface TextAction {
  type: 'APPEND'|'UPPERCASE'
  payload?: string
}
const textReducerFunc = (state: TextState, action: TextAction) => {
  const props = state.props;
  if (props.disabled) return state; // disabled => no change

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'APPEND':
      const appendText = state.text + action.payload;
      props.onTextChanged?.(appendText); // notify the text has been modified
      return {...state, text: appendText};

    case 'UPPERCASE':
      const upperText = state.text.toUpperCase();
      props.onTextChanged?.(upperText); // notify the text has been modified
      return {...state, text: upperText};

    default:
      return state; // unknown type => no change
  } // switch
}
```

The usage of `useTextProcessor`:

```
export default function TxtEditor(props: TextEditorProps) {
  const [text, dispatch] = useTextProcessor('hello', props);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {text}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'APPEND', payload: ' world'})}>append 'world'</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'UPPERCASE'})}>uppercase</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Can you suggest to me how to use `useReducer` with dependency **without any hack**?

[Here my running sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-reducer-with-dependencies-t6twt?file=/src/TxtEditor.tsx:1287-1665)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend elevating the state into the parent component. You need an "onTextChange" listener. That tells me that the state is in the wrong component. I recommend putting it into the parent component.

```
type TextAction =
  | { type: 'APPEND'; payload?: string }
  | { type: 'UPPERCASE' }
  | { type: 'SET_DISABLED'; disabled: boolean };

interface TextState {
  text: string;
  disabled: boolean;
}

const textReducerFunc = (state: TextState, action: TextAction): TextState => {
  console.log(action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'APPEND': {
      if (state.disabled) return state;
      return { ...state, text: state.text + action.payload };
    }
    case 'UPPERCASE': {
      if (state.disabled) return state;
      return { ...state, text: state.text.toLocaleUpperCase() };
    }
    case 'SET_DISABLED':
      return { ...state, disabled: action.disabled };
  }
};

function useTextReducer() {
  return useReducer(textReducerFunc, {
    disabled: false,
    text: ''
  });
}

function TextBox({
  text,
  dispatch
}: {
  text: string;
  dispatch: Dispatch<TextAction>;
}) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <button onClick={handleAppendPress}>append 'world'</button>
      <button onClick={handleUppercaseClick}>uppercase</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  function handleAppendPress() {
    dispatch({ type: 'APPEND', payload: 'world' });
  }

  function handleUppercaseClick() {
    dispatch({ type: 'UPPERCASE' });
  }
}

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useTextReducer();
  const { text } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`the text changed: ${text}`);
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>is disabled: </label>
      <input
        checked={state.disabled}
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={handleDisabledChange}
      />
      <TextBox dispatch={dispatch} text={state.text} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  function handleDisabledChange() {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_DISABLED', disabled: !state.disabled });
  }
}
```

([code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xqedr8?file=index.tsx))

From what I see in your code (the buttons that are already in it) you probably want to move the "disabled" checkbox into the `TextBox` component, further removing redundancy in state setting.

Comment: but, on **every action** I must pass the `disabled` & `onTextChanged`. If there are a lot of actions & `TextProps` has many properties the code will be less readable & harder to update/maintain.

Comment: @HeyyyMarco I think I finally figured out what you want. Please check out the updated answer.

Comment: your `useTextReducer` is similar to my original `useTextProcessor`.
Set the dependencies at initial & watchdog updating the deps everytime the custom hook called.
What's the benefit using useEffect & updating via `dispatch` instead of direct assignment `state.depSomething = depSomething`?

`onTextChanged` is always different by reference on every render, so using `useEffect` is not different than direct assignment.

Comment: @HeyyyMarco Well, `dispatch` actually causes the hook to re-"render" while a simple assignment does not. I'm actually not sure what your use-case is here. I personally would move the `onTextChange` callback outside of the hook into the component. But you didn't seem to like that. Maybe someone else has a better idea but I seem to have struck my limitations.

Comment: I still stand by the argument that stage management has nothing to do with calling callbacks to parent components. The hook should be placed in the parent component and only the `value` (text) passed down. Then the `onChange` should dispatch the action directly in the parent component.

Comment: yeah, struck my limit too, spent my time for 3 days.

Comment: the actual thing I do is creating functional hooks something like `useHoverLeave`, `usePressRelease`, `useValidInvalid`, `usePopup`, `useThemes`. So creating a custom component is easy & fast because the behavior & props are already handled by the hooks.

Comment: @HeyyyMarco okay, I tried it one more time. If that's not what you want, I'm afraid I cannot help you :(

Comment: I think we have used the limit `useReducer`.  
A new kind of hook should be introduced: `useReducerWithDeps(reduceFunc, initialState, initializer, dependencies)`.  
And a `deps` parameter should be added into `reducerFunc(state, deps, action): newState`.

Comment: @HeyyyMarco honestly if what I've posted isn't enough, the issue might be your design/you trying to overoptimize. But hey, what do I know :D

Comment: yeah I know. Usually a react component is made up from `<AnotherComponents />` (UI composition). That I do is behavior composition via `useMyWeirdBehavior()`. Thank you sharing your time for solving my problem. Not a perfect design but it works.